# Join table in Mysql to create new table

Tags: mysql, join

How to join 2 tables in mysql database so as to create a third permanent table which is also updated as the other 2 tables are updated?

Comment: Use [a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment the creation of a view is as simple as:

```
create view permanent_join_table as select
```

Add your select statement from that point on and replace `permanent_join_table` with the name you require.